# XSLT to read xml content from a text file with no xml declaration or .xml file extension

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using named template and collection function of XSLT2.0 to feed a bunch of files for processing. These set of input files have the naming format like 'a.b.c.d' and have xml content, but neither with proper file extension like ".xml" nor contain xml declaration in the file content.

Thus the below error is thrown by Saxon XSLT processor

> Type error
> XPTY0004: Required item type of result of call to collection is node(); supplied value has
> item type xs:base64Binary
> Required item type of result of call to collection is node(); supplied value has item type xs:base64Binary`

When I change the file name extension to ".xml" or include xml declaration `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` in the input files, there is no such error and the processing is fine.

Is there a way to force `collection` function to treat all the input files as xml files by default? The syntax of collection function doesn't seems to have an attribute to specify content type.

Answer (score 1):

The `CollectionFinder` mechanism in Saxon is highly configurable, so it's not so much a question of whether you can do it, as what's the simplest way to do it.

I think it should be possible simply to add `"?content-type=application/xml"` to the end of the collection URI.

Or if you prefer to do it from the API, I think `configuration.registerFileExtension("", "application/xml")` should do the job.

Comment: can you please suggest on how to implement the second way? i.e. how to append "?content-type=application/xml" to collection URI? Couldn't find examples when searched online.
`<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('./folderName/?select=*')/*"/>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: It just becomes `collection('./folderName/?select=*;content-type=application/xml')`. Documentation is at https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections

Comment: I tried it, but the same error as mentioned in the original question is thrown still
`<xsl:apply-templates select="collection('./folderName/?select=*;content-type=application/xml')"/>`

Comment: If you want to follow it up with saxonica please post a repro in the bug tracker at saxonica.plan.io